# Dependencies in R package

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I recently tried to create a R package and in the DESCRIPTION file I saw that in the "depends" field I can insert the other packages that I need, like this,

```
Depends: R (> = 3.2.2), readxl, ltm
```

The "readxl" package has not a problem, but for "ltm" I get this error:

```
Error in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = NA, dep_compare = NA):
Dependency package ltm not available.
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... <Anonymous> -> load_all ->             
load_depends -> mapply -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What are the `ltm` dependencies? Maybe it requires a new R version

Comment: From ltm documentation:

Comment: Depends R (>= 2.14.0), MASS, msm, polycor

Comment: My R version is the newest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with a package yesterday.

1) Reinstall R.
2) Reinstall package with `DEPENDENCIES=TRUE`
3) If it doesn't work, install dependencies from source.

Comment: When i use `install.packages("ltm", dependencies = T)` i get this error `ERROR: dependency 'polycor' is not available for package 'ltm''`

Comment: I restarted the pc and it worked this time! Thank you!